# Отловить изменение содержимого div

Tags: javascript, jquery, виджет, javascript-events

У меня есть div, содержимое которого может меняться различными способами: например, весь его контент может быть изменён через innerHTML, или могут быть добавлены узлы через DOM-методы. Это может произойти через собственный javascript или через вызовы jQuery API, или через другие библиотеки.

Я хочу выполнить некоторый код, когда содержимое div изменится, но я абсолютно не контролирую, когда он изменится. Действительно, я разрабатываю плагин, который может использоваться другими людьми, которые могут свободно изменять содержимое своих div'ов так, как они предпочитают. Когда внутреннее содержимое этого div изменяется, форма плагина также может быть обновлена.

Я использую jQuery. Есть ли способ отловить изменение содержимого div?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ([поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20observer))

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => console.log(mutations));
observer.observe(test, { 
  attributes: true, 
  childList: true,      
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
});

test.innerHTML = '1';
test.classList.add('test');
test.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
test.innerHTML += '2';
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: осторожно, это код выводит слишком много текста в консоль, что может привести к временному зависанию браузера

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать `DOMNodeInserted` и `DOMNodeRemoved`, чтобы проверить, добавлены или удалены элементы. К сожалению, IE не поддерживает это.

```
$('#myDiv').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
        alert('Content added! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert('Content removed! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Можно сохранить исходное содержимое и будущие изменения с помощью `.data()`. Вот пример.

```
var div_eTypes = [],
    div_changes = [];
$(function() {
    $('#myDiv').each(function() {
        this['data-initialContents'] = this.innerHTML;
    }).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        div_eTypes.concat(e.type.match(/insert|remove/));
        div_changes.concat(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

Пример вывода:

```
> $('#myDiv').data('initialContents');
"<h1>Привет мир!</h1><p>Это пример.</p>"
> div_eTypes;
["insert", "insert", "remove"]
> div_changes;
["<iframe src='http://example.com'></iframe>", "<h4>IANA — Example domains</h4><iframe src='http://example.com'></iframe>", "<h4>IANA – Example domains</h4>"]
```

Возможно, вы захотите включить `DOMSubtreeModified`, так как `DOMNodeInserted` и `DOMNodeRemoved` не запускаются, если элементы заменены через `innerHTML`. Он не работает в IE, но, по крайней мере, он отлично работает в других браузерах.

Comment: В чем прикол перевода 6-ти летней давности, когда есть это уже устарело и можно использовать другие вещи, а для IE есть решения?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, даже не знаю. Пока не нашёл. Везде пишут про эти события