# Как отследить появление элемента, подгружаемого асинхронным кодом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Вопрос тривиальный. Прикручен js-плагин с появлением на странице кнопки (`async="async"`). Хотелось бы изменить css-стиль кнопки, но я не могу отследить ее появление. Пробовал

```
$(elem).on("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
  console.log($(this));
}
```

Но мой скрипт упорно не видит нового элемента.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отловить изменение содержимого div](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693116/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-div)

Comment: Нет, я смотрел.

Comment: Относительно новые технологии js не поддерживаются в некоторых мобильных браузерах, даже const и let вызывают ошибку.

Comment: какой кнопки стиль вы хотите изменить? не той что ли которая появляется? Если этой кнопки не было, и она появилась, зачем менять стиль, почему бы не прописать его изначально?

Comment: @teran, это сторонний плагин, у меня нет доступа к его коду.

Comment: кто мешает на странице прописать стиль для `button[async="async"]` ? или менять что-то другое надо?

Comment: @ teran, сделайте ответом. Что-то я протупил. Действительно, ввело в заблуждение, что css-свойства прописаны кодом js, подумал, что нельзя изменить обычным правилом css. Указал opacity:0.4!important и все заработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения стилей появляющейся сторонней кнопки достаточно обычным образом описать стиль, используя соответствующий селектор. В большинстве случаев этого будет достаточно.

```
button[async="async"] {
       color: red !important;
}
```